# Change VSEnterprise subscription access level to Basic after removing VSE subscription from user

Tags: azure-devops

Some Azure DevOps users need to become Basic users instead of VS Enterprise users, because these users got another role in our organisation.

I removed the VS Enterprise subscription from these users in the MS partner portal (partner.microsoft.com). But Azure DevOps still sees the previously assigned VSE subscription for the users. And I cannot change the access level to Basic because Azure DevOps somehow detects the VSE subscription on the user.

How can I change the access level for the affected users?

Thanks for the input.

Comment: I do not think the system are constantly synchronized: I will wait 24 hours and then open a support ticket on either systems.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Azure Devops only validates the subscription when the user is added. So remove the user from the organization and then re-add them after removing the subscription should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Update to this since Eddie's answer is out of date

As of this date, Azure DevOps will automatically change access level based on Visual Studio Subscription (assuming the user is tied to the same email address in AzDO that their VS sub is tied to).  You DO NOT have to remove the user from Azure DevOps and add them back in to get Visual Studio Subscription changes to appear in AzDo.

Scenario I observed 02/03/2021

Existing AzDO user had access level of: Visual Studio Professional subscription.  User had license upgraded to Visual Studio Enterprise subscription on 02/02/2021.  User logged out and back in on 02/03/2021 and access level updated correctly.